# Functoriality of Br(X)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety over a field $k$, $k \subset K$ is a field extension, and $X_K = X \times_{Spec(k)} Spec(K)$. We have a map $X \to X_K$. By functoriality of the Brauer group, we have a map $Br(X) \to Br(X_K)$. My question is: is the image of $A \in Br(X)$ under this map equal to $A \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_{X_K}$?

Comment: I suppose $A$ is an Azumaya algebra? If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is any morphism of schemes, the map $f^*:\mathrm{Br}(Y)\rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(X)$ (what you call "functoriality of the Brauer group") is defined by pull back of Azumaya algebras.

Comment: Thanks. One more quick question: when people talk of the "natural map" $Br(X) \to Br(\bar{X})$, I thought they were using the inclusion $X \to \bar{X}$ and functoriality of $Br$. But, as you rightly point out, Br is contravariant. So what is this natural map $Br(X) \to Br(\bar{X})$?

Comment: There is no inclusion $X \rightarrow \overline{X}$, but there is a projection going the other way. :)

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!